# adding two elements of array in new array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
[0] => Text1 
[1] => Text2
```

I want to create this:

```
[0] => [0] => Text1 
       [1] => Text2
```

This is my code but does not working good:

```
$final_arr = array( Text1, Text2 );
$final = array();
foreach($final_arr as $pro){
    $final[] = $pro;    
}       
return $final;
```

Any help?

Comment: Uh... `$final = array($final_arr);`

Comment: `$newArray[] = $oldArray;` - or in your terms: `$final[] = $final_array;`

Comment: Thanks, its working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a loop for this, you can simply add the old array to a new array, and it will keep this form.

```
$final_arr = array('Text1', 'Text2');
$final = array($final_arr);
```

Alternate syntax:

```
$final_arr = array('Text1', 'Text2');
$final[] = $final_arr;
```

If you are returning this inside a function, you don't even need to reassign it to a new variable at all.

```
$final_arr = array('Text1', 'Text2');
return [$final_arr]; //or array($final_arr)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Text1
            [1] => Text2
        )

)
```

I suggest reading [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) regarding arrays.

Comment: @doki Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap your $final_arr in a new array.

```
$final_arr = array (Text1, Text2);
$final = array($final_arr);
return $final;
```